# Testing Prototype custom events with Jasmine

Tags: prototypejs, jasmine

I'm posting this for those that still use PrototypeJS and want to test custom events using [jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine) and [jasmine-prototype](https://github.com/masylum/jasmine-prototype) plugin.

We're triggering custom events based on users clicks or form submits. We wanted a simple way to test that the custom events is fired correctly.

Here is an example:

```
var CustomEventsDispatcher = ( function() {
   function init(){

    //if elements exists
    if($$('a.trigger_bomb')) {
        // Observe the elements
        $$(elements).each(function(element) {
            element.observe('click', function(e) {
                this.fire("bomb:explode", {})
            });
        });
    }


    return {'init' : init};
 })();
```

Using resources available on the web, I've created a fixture ...

```
 // spec/fixtures/links.html
 <a class="trigger_bomb" href="#"> Trigger Bomb </a>
```

... and a test suite:

```
  //spec/trigger_bomb_spec.js
 describe("Trigger Bombs", function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
       loadFixtures("links.html")
       CustomEventsDispatcher.init();
   })

   it("should raise the custom event", function(){
      var element=$$('a.trigger_bomb').first();
      spyOnEvent(element, 'click');
      element.click();

      expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(element);
      expect('bomb:explode').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(element);
   });
 });
```

The first assertion works fine, but not the second. The reason is that `spyOnEvent` alters the way click events are handled on `element`.

Comment: There are plenty of developers that still use PrototypeJS. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to mock the `fire` function like this:

```
  //spec/trigger_bomb_spec.js
 describe("Trigger Bombs", function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
       loadFixtures("links.html")
       CustomEventsDispatcher.init();
   })

   it("should raise the custom event", function(){
      var element=$$('a.trigger_bomb').first();
        spyOn(element, 'fire')
        element.click()
        expect(element.fire).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bomb:explode', {})
   });
 });
```

However this solution has a side effect : the click will be executed which will cause the jasmine page result to reload continuously. You need to intercept click events and stop the default behavior with a global `beforeEach` hook:

```
// spec/helpers/spec_helper.js
beforeEach(function(){

    // stop all clicks from fixtures 
    // (but allow clicks from the user in the jasmine result page)
    document.observe('click', function(e){
        var element = e.findElement('#HTMLReporter')
        if (element == document)   {
            Event.stop(e)
        }
    })             
})
```

Hope this will help someone to save a few hours of debugging :). Feel free to comment / improve / propose a better alternative.